# Negotitate VRRP on a private link between routers (Possible?)

Tags: high-availability, failover, vrrp

I have a topology similar to this one:

- R1 and R2 are two physical machines acting as routers. (Running some linux distro with Keepalived)
- R1 and R2 are connected to one another with a private link.
- R1 and R2 have both one downstream connection, which is the one I'd like to have the VIP advertised.

However, I'd like the negotitation of Master/Backup to be to be done on the private link. I'm not entirely sure what we want to do is feasible though, I'm looking for someone who can clear me out on this.

I'm looking for the proper failover in case any of the two interfaces every R has fails.

Is this possible?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly possible.  Using heartbeat, for example, one might say in `ha.cf`

```
bcast eth2
```

where `eth2` is the private interface to the heartbeat pair.  Communication between the two for the purposes of deciding who's primary will then take place on that interface.

That said, I'm curious about your statement that

> I'm looking for the proper failover in case any of the two interfaces
>   every R has fails

If these boxes are routers, they'll presumably need two interfaces anyway, in order to route from one network to another, and vice-versa (modulo VLANs, edge routers, etc.).  If you want an interface for private comms between the pair, you'll need a third NIC.